# VBA data entry messes up date format and filter for column

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have made a GUI for entering data into my excel table.
[image]

The date value is entered via the textbox "Gremientermin" and the VBA code looks like this:

```
diesesworkbook.Sheets("Termine").Range("B" & (lastrow + 1)).Value = Format(Termineingabe.TextBox3.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

but if I enter some data with date then the filter for the column looks like this:
[image]

You see 16.02.2023 is just text and no real date value. How can I get this working?

Comment: When inserting the value, don't format it --> `format` turns the value into text. Instead try using `cdate`

Comment: If you do want the date to be shown a specific way (not your standard local format), you'll have to use .Numberformat on the range you're placing it in. Also don't forget you can rename your textboxes to something more recognizable so it's easier to read when coding around it.